# Does formsflow will automatically logged out if the user is idle for a long time

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

Suppose once the user is logged in and then he/she is not active/idle for a long time, does the user session will automatically logged out?
Is there any security added like same user cannot login from multiple system at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Same user can login from different systems . The user's won't be logged out of the system once the user logs in from another system. We can configure session time/ idle time logout from Keycloak settings however.